# can not get the server play auto install app in the google setupwizard

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Play Auto Installs problem.I have uploaded PAI applications on Google Parner website.The local Android ROM developed has also been integrated with GMS.No related pages of auto install apps appear in the setupwizard, it looks like the PAI application of the server could not be downloaded locally.

Here are some logs:

```
03-25 00:55:54.174 2132-4868/com.android.vending I/Finsky: [236] com.google.android.finsky.setup.d.a.e.e(56): Received EarlyUpdate with 0 entries
03-25 00:55:54.186 2132-4874/com.android.vending I/Finsky: [240] com.google.android.finsky.setup.al.a(38): Prefetching preloads for account null
03-25 00:55:54.187 2132-4874/com.android.vending W/Finsky: [240] com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.c.e(708): For unauth, use getDfeApiNonAuthenticated() instead!
03-25 00:55:54.200 2132-4875/com.android.vending I/Finsky: [241] com.google.android.finsky.setup.o.call(12): Found VPA stub android.autoinstalls.config.tcl.device:1
03-25 00:55:54.204 2132-4876/com.android.vending I/Finsky: [242] com.google.android.finsky.deviceconfig.t.a(14): Start requesting GCM Reg Id
03-25 00:55:54.724 2132-2132/com.android.vending W/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.application.impl.c.e(708): For unauth, use getDfeApiNonAuthenticated() instead!
03-25 00:55:54.935 2132-2132/com.android.vending E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.deviceconfig.g.a(6): Couldn't upload device config
    [2] com.google.android.finsky.setup.fetchers.w.a(3): Could not get device config token, proceeding with preloads anyway
```

Comment: By any chance, did you solve your issue?